# commandx optional arguments

Tags: pdftex, optional-arguments

I have a custom command for the package `todonotes`

```
\newcommandx{\custom}[3][1=]{\todo[#1,author=#2]{#3}}
```

which is supposed to be used like:

```
\custom[inline]{author1,some comments}
```

Instead, it raises the error:

```
E: main.tex:124 Package xkeyval Error: `some comments' undefined in families `todonotes'
```

What is going on? I've defined 3 arguments with argument 1 as optional!

Comment: You are only specifying two parameters, it should probably read `\custom[inline]{author1}{some comments}`. In your case, you are using `\todo[inline,author=author1,some comments]` where `some comments` is an invalid key for the `todonotes` package.

Comment: Rather than `xargs`, I'd use `xparse` and `\NewDocumentCommand{\custom}{O{}mm}{\todo[#1,author=#2]{#3}}` with a call such as `\custom[inline]{author1}{whatever}`. More robust.

Comment: Any news here ?